# matrix with different size font

Tags: math-mode

does anyone have an idea, how to make equal font size of the following matrix ??
thanks in advance

```
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\dot x_{1}\\
\\
\dot x_{2}\\
\\
\dot x_{3} 
\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{2}\\
\\
g-\frac{c}{m}  \left(\frac{x_3}{x_1} \right )^2\\
\\
\frac{R}{L} x_3+ \frac{2c}{L} \left (\frac{x_2 x_3}{x_1^2} \right) +\frac{1}{L}u
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: equal size of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about fractions. In that case use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`. Also remember that `amsmath` provides `bmatrix` environment that is easier to use and better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\dot x_{1}\\[3ex]
\dot x_{2}\\[3ex]
\dot x_{3}
\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{2}\\[2ex]
g-\dfrac{c}{m}  \left(\dfrac{x_3}{x_1} \right )^2\\[3ex]
\dfrac{R}{L} x_3+ \dfrac{2c}{L} \left (\dfrac{x_2 x_3}{x_1^2} \right) +\dfrac{1}{L}u
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot x_{1}\\[3ex]
\dot x_{2}\\[3ex]
\dot x_{3}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{2}\\[2ex]
g-\dfrac{c}{m}  \left(\dfrac{x_3}{x_1} \right )^2\\[3ex]
\dfrac{R}{L} x_3+ \dfrac{2c}{L} \left (\dfrac{x_2 x_3}{x_1^2} \right) +\dfrac{1}{L}u
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Don't leave empty rows in order to space out the matrix.
Instead, equalize the row heights by inserting a “phantom” of the desired size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\newcommand{\dfracstrut}{\vphantom{\left(\dfrac{x_1}{x_1}\right)^2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot x_{1} \dfracstrut \\
\dot x_{2} \dfracstrut \\
\dot x_{3} \dfracstrut
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{2} \dfracstrut \\
g-\dfrac{c}{m}\left(\dfrac{x_3}{x_1}\right)^{\!2} \dfracstrut\\
\dfrac{R}{L} x_3+ \dfrac{2c}{L} \left (\dfrac{x_2 x_3}{x_1^2} \right) +\dfrac{1}{L}u
  \dfracstrut
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The `\dfracstrut` command will just be defined for that `equation`.

[image]

Don't use the `cmex10` option to `amsmath` unless your TeX distribution is more than 15 years old.